# e.recordSave event not being fired on Summer 17 (Communities) It was working before

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, locker-service

We have a partial sandbox to test our app for the new release (Summer 17). And we are facing a issue with the force:recordEdit component.

We have a pretty simple component:

**quickForm.cmp**:

```
<force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
<ui:button class="slds-button--brand slds-p-horizontal--large slds-p-ertical--xx-small" label="{!$Label.c.BPSave}" press="{!c.save}"/>
```

**quickFormController.js**:

```
save: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find('edit').get('e.recordSave').fire();
    console.log('save');
}
```

The event is fired once I change the code, but if I refresh the page the event stop firing. Here's a quick video for a better understanding:

http://recordit.co/crQRckYsci